# Delaying on Edit Function to Insert Timestamp

Tags: google-apps-script

When the status in Column A is changed to "Completed" the row is being moved to another tab called "Archive". I have tried to edit my existing script to insert a timestamp in Column C when the status is changed to "Completed", however the script runs too fast and doesn't insert the timestamp.

I have tried to insert a delay function after the getRange function, but it did not input a date at all. I have also tried to create a trigger delay and did not have any success.

```
function onEdit(event) {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var r = event.source.getActiveRange();


  if(s.getName() == "Terminations" && r.getColumn() == 1 && r.getValue() == "Completed") {
    var row = r.getRow();
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Processed Terminations");
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
    s.deleteRow(row);
  }
}
```

In Column C, I would like the a timestamp to be inserted when a row is marked as "Complete"

Comment: This code doesn't even try to write to the spreadsheet - it just moves a row. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve && https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function onEdit(event) {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var r = event.source.getActiveRange();


  if(s.getName() == "Terminations" && r.getColumn() == 1 && r.getValue() == "Completed") {
    event.range.getSheet().getRange(event.range.rowStart,3).setValue(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getTimeZone(), "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss"));
    var row = r.getRow();
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Processed Terminations");
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
    s.deleteRow(row);
  }
}
```

Comment: Also, how do you have the cursor as flowers?? so cute!